# Python3 Try/Except Block

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, try-catch, except

Can someone please help me understand the following issue...

I'm having problems executing my try/except block in my simple number guessing game. The function containing my error handling works fine if I remove the integer portion of the initial input. But if I do this, the rest of the game doesn't work, because from my understanding Python3 takes input and stores it as a string. So how can I get my exception to execute? Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

```
# number game
import random




print ("Welcome to the guessing number game!\n\n")

winning_number= random.randrange(1, 11)
guess = int(input("Can you guess the lucky number.\nHint it's between 1 and 10!\n"))


def is_number(guess):
    try:
        int(guess)
    except ValueError:
        print ('You need to type a number\n')
        guess = int((input("Please input a number\n")))
        game(guess)



def compare(guess):
    if guess > winning_number:
        print ("Wrong, you're guess is too high.\n")
        guess = int(input("Guess againn\n"))
        game(guess)
    else:
        print ("Wrong, you're guess is too low.\n")
        guess = int(input("Guess again\n"))
        game(guess)



def game(guess):
    is_number(guess)
    if guess == winning_number:
        print ("You win!, You guessed the number!")
    else:
        compare(guess)

game(guess)
```

Here is what I get when I input anything other than an integer...

Welcome to the guessing number game!

Can you guess the lucky number.
Hint it's between 1 and 10!
f
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mickyj209/PycharmProjects/Practice/NumberGuess.py", line 10, in 
    guess = int(input("Can you guess the lucky number.\nHint it's between 1 and 10!\n"))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'f'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: What's the issue you're having?

Comment: If the initial input is anything other than an integer the except portion of my function does not execute like it should. I still get a ValueError.

Comment: Your game seems fine, share us the input that causes the problems

Comment: Protip for the future: `random.randint` makes more sense for assigning `winning_number`.

Comment: Adding my error to the post....

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to save the value that time (`guess = int(guess)`), you're not `return`ing anything there, and you're just having the program run the function but not making a decision based on the result. You also have an `int(input(...` in the exception handling, which could itself generate an exception which won't be caught. The initial guess isn't in a `try` block, either.

You could refactor this program:

```
def game():

    print ("Welcome to the guessing number game!\n\n")

    winning_number = random.randrange(1, 11)
    print("Can you guess the lucky number?\nHint: it's between 1 and 10!\n")
    while 1:
        try:
            guess = int(input("Please input a number\n"))
        except ValueError:
            continue
        if guess > winning_number:
            print('Wrong - your guess is too high.')
        elif guess < winning_number:
            print('Wrong - your guess is too low.')
        else:
            print('You win! You guessed the number!')
            break
```

Comment: OP also forgot to check if the input is a number the first time they convert to an int.

Comment: You're missing an `input` somewhere.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. But as I am learning to code here, why do I still get a ValueError when I have an exception for it?

Comment: Sorry for the rapid-fire edits - every time I take another look at your program I find another problem. :P